# Different return statement according to number of elements requested in python

Tags: python

How can I do something like this in a function in python?

```
def cool():
    if (user wants to receive one element):
        return 10
    if (user wants to receice two elements):
        return 4, 2 
 
a = cool()
print(a) # 10

x, y = cool()
print(x) # 4
print(y) # 2
```

Comment: How is the function supposed to know what the user wants? You need a parameter to control this behaviour.

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question, which invalidates one or more answers, is against policy on Stack Overflow. Your edit here did so. The policy is that other users with edit privileges should proactively revert such changes. I have reverted your edit. You *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](/questions/ask)*, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Comment: In creating a new question, it may help to have the Markdown which you used when changing this one. You can find that Markdown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/c6059c06-eea2-486f-b9d4-5ff2fc4f01bf/view-source).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a list and splicing that. The function below takes a list and slices it at a users return count.

```
def returnCount(returns,numbers):
    return numbers[:returns]
print(returnCount(3,[1,2,3,4,5]))
```

output

```
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use an array.

```
def cool():
    if (user wants to receive one element):
        return [10]
    if (user wants to receice two elements):
        return [4, 2] 
 
a = cool()
for value in a:
    print(value)
#or just
print(a)

#if you want everything to print on one line:
outputString = ""
for value in a:
    outputString += str(value) + " "
    #might have to do outputString = outputString + str(value) + " "
print(outputString)
```

Comment: I don't think it can be done in the way your example used unless you always return the same number of variables and use a dummy value so you know which ones aren't 'valid'

Answer (score -1):

You could pass it to the function as an argument.

```py
def cool(return_values):
    if return_values == 1:
        return 10
    elif return_values == 2:
        return 4, 2 
 
a = cool(1)
print(a) # 10

x, y = cool(2)
print(x) # 4
print(y) # 2
```